# How to call function in javascript with parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a few image with url. Each id has custom value. For example: id="bg_234".

```
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg_234" /></a>

<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg_34444" /></a>
```

How can I run function below with custom id value ?

```
$(function() {
 $('.menulink').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
 });
});
```

King regards

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, what you want to do?.

Comment: do you want select $("#bg_34444") or $("#bg_234") based on .menulink clicked ?

Comment: with id you cannot create a function since id is unique to document. you can use the tag name i.e img.

Comment: `e.target` should give you the link, so if the image is the first child of the links, e.target.firstCHild.id shoudl get the id attribute of the img.

Comment: @Shilly: If the click is on the `img`, `e.target` will be the `img`, not the `a`. Justinas' answer covers handling it.

Comment: @BekimBacaj i think you want to use e.currentTarget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-selecting element by id, use `$(this)` to refer to currently clicked element and than simply do [`.find('img')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get image element:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menulink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
    });
});
```

---

If you still need ID for some reasons, use [`$(this).attr('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: i see that the anchor doesn't have id , $(this).find('img').attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menulink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  var $anchor =  $(this); //$(this) to refer to currently clicked element which has ".menulink" class
  $anchor.find('img[id^="bg_"]').attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg_234" /></a>

<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg_34444" /></a>
```